# Excel is plotting my date x-axis completely wrong, and I cannot work out why

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a very simple Excel data set which plots 15-minute date/time segments against values.

When I try to plot it as a line graph in Excel (mac), Excel inexplicably renders the results wrongly. It seems to plot only one value for each day, and I cannot determine how it is picking which value to show.

The only way I can get it plotted correctly is by changing the data into a Pivot table and then it plots fine, even though the data is exactly the same.

You can see some sample data here with the Excel rendering:

[image]

Comment: The value its showing for each day is the sum total of the 15 minute increment values for that day.

Comment: I tried it with 10 lines of data at 15 minutes increments, the line chart rendered no problem.
Now that I think about it, could it be that you have so many increments that there are too many to show so it combines all increments for each date?
Click and drag to highlight 20 rows instead and then try and render a line chart. If it works, then my theory is correct that you simply have too many lines to render in a chart.

Comment: So I did a further test. I reduced to just a few data points, and did a chart. I also then did a pivot table with the exact same data. 

You can see in the screenshot that it renders the pivot table correctly, but not the normal chart. 

It doesn't appear to be the sum total @NetServOps. It actually appears to be plotting all the data points in one. See the other screen shot.

Comment: Screenshots:
https://ibb.co/6gHBryx
https://ibb.co/PmdpsMy

Comment: In the second screenshot, what kind of chart are you trying to render there? It looks like perhaps trying to create a clustered chart?

Comment: It is just the normal line chart - see https://ibb.co/7Ntch32

Comment: Try right-clicking on the line and choosing 'Format data series...'

Look for 'Gap Width' in the 'Format Data Series' box that pops up.

See if the gap is 0%. If it is, then make it anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the data labels (i,e,e the dates on the chart), select "Format Axis". Under Axis Options -> Axis style, choose "Text Axis"

[image]

Comment: You sir are a genius. That fixed it!!!! Thank you Mr Cybernetic Nomad.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -

Highlight cells with the dates - Data Tab -  Text to columns - Delimited - Next- Tick Tab - Next - Click Date:DMY - finish.

No idea why!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).